# Возможна ли такая форма изложения мысли?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли так выразиться?

Это иностранное слово обозначает русское слово "давать"

Answer (score 2):

Такая форма изложения мысли невозможна, так как слова обозначают понятия, а между словами в разных языках существует **соответствие** в том случае, если они обозначают одинаковые понятия.

Поэтому надо сказать так:

Это иностранное  слово соответствует русскому слову ***давать***.